# How to display values in spring form:input from arrayList?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have an arraylist containing some fields values of which i need to display in text fields. I am using spring form for this purpose. My area of concern i am not being able to display the field values because there is a parent bean in place.
I know we can do something like this   form:input path="xxx" value="${arraylist.get(0).element}"  , however i am not being able to understand how to access the elements when they are wrapped in a parent bean. Please help!

Comment: Not sure whether it is possible to bind directly to generic collections with Spring. It would be better to use wrapper bean as suggested by Debojit Saikia.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `wrapper` parent bean, which contains `Child` instances in it:

```
class Parent{

Child child;
...
}
```

and assuming you have a list containing instances of this `Parent`; you can display the properties of `child` as below:

```
<c:forEach var="parent" items="${parents}" varStatus="status">
<form:input path="parents[${status.index}].child.childProperty" />
</c:forEach>
```